# Make dir with php and html form

Tags: php, html, mkdir

i'm trying to make a new folder using php and html form using path : `uploads/$loggedInUser->username$actfolder` but no success and i want to delete it aswel :

php

```
<?php
include("db-settings.php");
include("config.php");
$foldername = $_POST['foldername'];

$path = "uploads/$loggedInUser->username
" . $foldername;
mkdir($path);
header('Location:myfiles.php')
?>
```

html

```
<form action="mkdir.php" method="post">
<input type="text name="foldername" id="foldername">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the line break.

```
$path = 'uploads/' . $loggedInUser->username . '/' . $foldername;
```

If that doesn't work, you are likely having a permissions problem.

Also, your approach is completely insecure!  Anyone can post `../` in their username and put a directory wherever they want in your file system.

Finally, when you specify a `Location:` header, you must use a full URL.  Most browsers will accept a relative resource like you have, but not all.

Comment: All browsers should accept relative URLs, because HTTP is being changed to allow it.

Comment: @Barmar It hasn't changed yet.

Comment: @Barmar It's trivial to prepend your base URL yourself.  If you don't know what it is, you can derive it from the requested path and host.  I believe in following the standards as much as possible.  There is no reason not to.  I see nothing wrong with pointing out the fact that not including the full URL is currently non-standard, especially since I indicated that most browsers will still work just fine.